# DefaultFormattingConversionService not loaded in test context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

What is the requirement for DefaultFormattingConversionService to be loaded into the application context?

I'm running to very similar java services, both using Spring xml config. I have to create a bean containing duration properties, which is possible due to DateTimeFormatterRegistrar's ability to convert a `String` to a `Duration`. Everything works just fine for both projects in production, but in test context, one project fails with

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.Duration] for property 'foobar': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

My test setup looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/foo/bar.xml")
public class ControllerTest {

    private MockMvc _mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext _context;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        _mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(_context).build();
    }
```

This works for one project, but does not for the other. I compared the xml configs multiple times and couldn't find anything causing this mismatch. DefaultFormattingConversionService seems to not have any special requirements to be loaded(?). Any hint is appreciated!

Spring version: 4.2.8.RELEASE

Spring Boot version: 1.3.8.RELEASE

Comment: Because you aren't using Spring Boot in your test. I suggest a read of the testing chapter of the spring boot reference guide.

Comment: It's the same test setup for the other project where it just works.

Comment: If it works or not depends on your xml file (why do you even have that). Bu generally you are using spring Boot then also you should use the correct way of testing with that framework.